# Why RichTextBox append text in async Task no need Invoke?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I have asynchronous programming counter and print to richtextbox as below.

```
private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task task = uplineCount();
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    rtCount.AppendText("mmmmmm");
                }));
            });

            Task.WhenAll(task);
        }

        public async Task uplineCount()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nuMaxValue.Value; i++)
            {
                rtCount.AppendText(i.ToString() + "\n");

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
```

**Why i don't need Invoke when AppendText in uplineCount method?**

Comment: FYI: You seem to be intending to use the synchronous method `Task.WaitAll` that blocks until the tasks complete, but you're actually using `Task.WhenAll` which returns a `Task` you're not awaiting.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar It the same `async event` with `await uplineCount()`.

Comment: I think you might want to reread what I said.

Comment: The continuation executes in a ThreadPool Thread, while the first call executes in the current SynchronizationContext. You can add `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to the continuation to resume in the same context. -- You could simply make the handler async and await the first method, add the rest of the code (which is just `rtCount.AppendText("mmmmmm");`) after. -- You should disable the Button in any case, until all code there is run.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar 
Thank you, but that's not what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @Yune Yes, I know that. If I thought that was your question, I would have told you about that in an answer. If I saw someone about to touch something I knew was so hot that it would burn them, but they were seemingly oblivious to the danger, I would warn them. This is what I've done here.

Comment: @Jimi Oh. I'm meaning `task uplineCount` run at mainThread but `ContinueWith` is not.
That's right?

Comment: Pretty much. The continuation uses the default scheduler here, so it's executed in a ThreadPool Thread. If you remove `Invoke()` your should have a cross-thread exception. If you specify `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`, it executes in the current SynchronizationContext, the calling Thread context. -- Anyway, the code you have there is not well constructed, you need to refactor it. The continuation is not needed.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I know you want good for me. But I have to finish without using `async await`, `Task.Run` in event. This is my solution and I'm trying to understand it more deeply

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the execution of your method is no different if you have the `Task.WhenAll(task);` line. I expect you really just want `private async void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and then `await task;` instead of `Task.WhenAll(task);`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I understand. I also said it's the same before